# How to count the number of times a record has been modified in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains the which contains the row id as the primary key and other columns like Mon , Tue, Wed ...

Whenever there is a save operation a row is created in DB.

I want to figure out how many times the data has been modified in DB.

For example consider the table

```
ID   Mon  Tue Wed     
1     Y    Y   Y    
2     Y    N   Y    
3     N    Y   Y    
4     N    Y   Y
```

What I want to know is how many times the record has been modified.

Looking at the above the table , the outcome  should be 3 as there are 3 unique records.

Unique record means current record is different from last record.

Comment: I can't imagine this would scale to 100s or millions of records.  SUGGESTION: why not add a new column, for "OriginalRecordID".  Then "Unique record means current record's OriginalRecordID is null", and being able to count (or list) all modifications becomes much easier/much more efficient (more efficient than a full table scan).  Just a thought...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: We have date filter to restrict the no of rows, scaling is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using subquery

```
select count(*)
from
(
   select distinct Mon , Tue, Wed from your_table
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach could be using `dense_rank` if your dbms support

```
select sum(total)
 (
 select case when
 dense_rank() over(partition by Mon,Tue,Wed order by id )=1 then 1 else 0 end as total
 from cte
 ) t
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2ccafb15bbddcde1d230897eff3cfbf)

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(mon) over (order by id) as prev_mon,
             lag(tue) over (order by id) as prev_tue,
             lag(wed) over (order by id) as prev_wed
      from t
     ) t
where prev_mon is null or
      prev_mon <> mon or
      prev_tue <> tue or
      prev_wed <> wed;
```

Note that this handles the case where the values "return" to previous values.  So this data:

```
ID   Mon  Tue Wed     
1     Y    Y   Y    
2     Y    N   Y    
3     N    Y   Y    
4     N    Y   Y    
5     Y    Y   Y
```

counts as 4, not 3.  If you wanted 3 -- the number of distinct entries in the table, then simply do:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct mon, tue, wed
      from t
     ) t;
```

Or, as some databases support:

```
select count(distinct mon, tue, wed)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing the point or can you not just add an extra column that gets incremented every time you do an update? Would be far simpler to query one value that trying to calculate it from a full table scan?

Comment: The data base can't be altered. It's already there for so long.